# I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named _socket on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ubuntu, anaconda

I installed Anaconda3 on ubuntu and changed the path to ~/anaconda/bin in .bashrc file then I'm trying to install keras It's throwing this error.

```
hemanth@specter:~$ python3 -m pip install keras
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hemanth/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/hemanth/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/hemanth/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/home/hemanth/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/home/hemanth/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/home/hemanth/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 7, in <module>
    from socket import error as SocketError, timeout as SocketTimeout
  File "/home/hemanth/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this command and it is working fine.

however, try to install socket using `pip install sockets` and then again try installing keras.

Comment: Tried that, even that didn't work. Same error again.